# Jenkins - matrix jobs - variables on different slaves overwrite each other?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I think i dont get how matrix builds work. When i set some variable in some stage depending on which node i run, then on rest of the stage sometimes this variable is set as it should and sometimes it gets values from other nodes (axes). In example below its like job which runs on ub18-1 sometimes has VARIABLE1='Linux node' and sometimes is VARIABLE1='Windows node'. Or gitmethod sometimes it is created from LinuxGitInfo and sometimes WindowsGitInfo.

Source i based on 
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix

Script almost exactly the same as real one

```
@Library('firstlibrary') _
import mylib.shared.*
pipeline {
    parameters {
        booleanParam name: 'AUTO', defaultValue: true, description: 'Auto mode sets some parameters for every slave separately'
        choice(name: 'SLAVE_NAME', choices:['all', 'ub18-1','win10'],description:'Run on specific platform')
        string(name: 'BRANCH',defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Preferably common label for entire group')
        booleanParam name: 'SONAR', defaultValue: false, description: 'Scan and gateway'
        booleanParam name: 'DEPLOY', defaultValue: false, description: 'Deploy to Artifactory'

    }

    agent none

    stages{
        stage('BuildAndTest'){
            matrix{
                agent {
                    label "$NODE"
                }
                when{ anyOf{
                    expression { params.SLAVE_NAME == 'all'}
                    expression { params.SLAVE_NAME == env.NODE}  
                }}
                axes{
                    axis{
                        name 'NODE'
                        values 'ub18-1', 'win10'
                    }
                }
                stages{
                    stage('auto mode'){
                        when{
                            expression { return params.AUTO }
                        }
                        steps{
                            echo "Setting parameters for each slave"
                            script{
                                nodeLabelsList = env.NODE_LABELS.split()

                                if (nodeLabelsList.contains('ub18-1')){
                                    println("Setting params for ub18-1");
                                    VARIABLE1 = 'Linux node'
                                }

                                if (nodeLabelsList.contains('win10')){
                                    println("Setting params for Win10");
                                    VARIABLE1 = 'Windows node'
                                }

                                if (isUnix()){
                                    gitmethod = new LinuxGitInfo(this,env)
                                } else {
                                    gitmethod = new WindowsGitInfo(this, env)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stage('GIT') {
                        steps {                
                            checkout scm
                        }
                    }

                    stage('Info'){
                        steps{
                            script{
                                sh 'printenv' 

                                echo "branch: " +  env.BRANCH_NAME
                                echo "SLAVE_NAME: " + env.NODE_NAME
                                echo VARIABLE1


                                gitinfo = new GitInfo(gitmethod)
                                gitinfo.init()
                                echo gitinfo.author
                                echo gitinfo.id
                                echo gitinfo.msg
                                echo gitinfo.buildinfo
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    stage('install'){
                        steps{
                            sh 'make install'
                        }
                    }

                    stage('test'){
                        steps{
                            sh 'make test'
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are *env.NODE_LABELS* in *nodeLabelsList = env.NODE_LABELS.split()* ? And why don't you use **NODE** to decide which value will be assigned to *VARIABLE1*?

Comment: stupid Jenkins... https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i solved the problem by defining variables maps with node/slave names as keys. Some friend even suggested to define variables in yml/json file in repository and parse them. Maybe i will, but so far this works well

example:

before the pipelines

```
def DEPLOYmap = [
    'ub18-1': false,
    'win10': true
    ]
```

in stages

```
when {
        equals expected: true, actual: DEPLOYmap[NODE]
     }
```