# Jenkins workspace variable is swapping during parallel builds stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I got a WS variable which is saving the Jenkins WORKSPACE variable.
During stages I always check if the WS == WORKSPACE Jenkins generic variable.
What I saw that during parallel runs ( when 2 different workspaces are created inside C:/jenkins/workspace@1 and C:/jenkins/workspace@2 the $WORKSPACE is swapping between those 2 parallels builds.
[image]

The problem is reproduced rarely , less than 10 percent of cases but I find it quite strange , for the picture above -> The first workspace its AVB_Aplicattions_BOSCH-3 its going trough 3 stages and in the 4th stages the $WORKSPACE variable its swapping with AVB_APLICATTIONS_BOSCH-4( the other parallel build).If I will look on the other build (AVB_APLICATTIONS_BOSCH-4 I will see the same problem-> the workspace is becoming AVB_APLICATTIONS_BOSCH-3).
During this builds I compile using cmake files, I'm afraid that the results will be not correct.
I was thinking to use the in build dir() function during each stage to be sure im on the same workspace .
Some one know a good approach for this case and also why its happening?
I don't want to deactivate parallel's builds.

Comment: Show specific example how you define those variables and how you assign the values within your pipeline. That will allow to investigate better your situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Jenkins variable scopes aren't really safe with parallel stages (see further sources / link). There are actually several questions and answers (and workaround) how to work with variables when using parallel stages. Long story short: **don't use global variables but pay extra attention to define local variables with `def` to limit their scope**:

- [Jenkins - matrix jobs - variables on different slaves overwrite each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099474/jenkins-matrix-jobs-variables-on-different-slaves-overwrite-each-other/60258991#60258991)
- [Variables get overwritten in parallel stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049753/variables-get-overwritten-in-parallel-stages)
- [Parallel matrix and global variables without race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725684/parallel-matrix-and-global-variables-without-race-condition)

---

Jenkins community links:

- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55040
- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54732

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification ( I was not thinking the main problem was the variables itself), thanks for the documentation